# Ruby - convert string with negative number to int

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a query on a parameter that always returns a negative number, but as a string.

I need to convert that to an `int` so that I can use it.

```
 Parameter = InternetGatewayDevice.SystemConfig.Status.ModemStatus.RSRP
 Value = -87 (as string)
```

For example, when I run my query an the parameter above, I get the return value of `-87` presented as a `string`.

How do I convert that `string` to an `integer` so that I can perform mathematical calculations on it?

Comment: This isn't clear, could you elaborate your question?

Comment: Umm.... did you try `.to_i`? *e.g.*, `"-87".to_i`. Just read a little of the Ruby documentation.

Comment: I apologize, but my experience with ruby is only about 5 hours older than my original post.  The problem I am trying to solve is that my return value is a string and I need it to be an integer so that I can do math on it.  I hope that helps to clarify...

Answer (score 3):

```
irb(main):001:0> "-3".to_i
=> -3
```